# sql select query for impala column with map data type

Tags: sql, database, impala, cloudera-cdh

For a table, say details, with the schema as,

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| name | string |
| desc | map<int, string> |

How do I form a select query - to be run by java program - which expects the result set in this structure?

| name | desc |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | {1,"home"} |
| Alice | {2,"office"} |

Having in mind limitations in impala with regards to complex types [here](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_complex_types.html)

> The result set of an Impala query always contains all scalar types;
> the elements and fields within any complex type queries must be
> "unpacked" using join queries.

ie. `select * from details;` would only return results without the column with map type(complex type).

The closest I've come up with is `select name, map_col.key, map_col.value from details, details.desc map_col;`. Result set is not in expected format - obviously
.

Thanks in advance.